# Node.js http request not ending

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a problem with node.js http.request call. I want to call external api (in my case Openstack api).The request is sent successfully and i get the response, but my request does not finish after response is received. Instead it waits for about 2 minutes and then the request ends. When do the same REST call from a REST client like Postman, there is no waiting and everything works well.

Here is my code, the function is called when I do the GET request on /auth URL.

```
var options = {
    host: 'someIp',
    path: '/auth',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Host":"auth.api.someIp",
        "X-Auth-User":"username",
        "X-Auth-Key":"key"
    }
};

var request = http.request(options, function(response){
    var body = ""
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {            
        console.log('response end')
    });
});
request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
request.on('end', function() {
    console.log('request end');
});

request.end();
```

This is the console log:

response end
GET /auth 200 120080ms

My question is, why is request not ending when i do it with node.js http.request?

Comment: Make the request to "google.com" for example, if it works then it may be because of a header that you did not specified or is invalid.

Comment: I have tried the above, but everything is the same, still waits for about 2 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Mmh try listening for the finish event.

```
request.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('request end');
});
```

request is an instance of [Incoming Message](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage).

Comment: I have tried to listen to close and finish events. On close there is no change, and when i listen to finish event it writes output to console log but it still waits for about two minutes before it's done.

Comment: Maybe something with your username/key?

Comment: The api that i am connecting to is giving me back a valid response, so it can't be because of the username/key. So i get the response with all data needed but request is still not ending.